# Fragment with ViewPager that hosts a list of fragments; the ViewPager's setCurrentItem function stops working after I leave the host fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment, fragmentstatepageradapter

My program is designed such that a list of fragments are hosted in MainActivity and navigated through with the FragNav controller library. One of my main fragments has a ViewPager that hosts two other fragments. I've implemented an OnClick interface that switches fragments in the ViewPager based on a button click.

If I switch away from my main fragment and return to it, the ViewPager populates with the most recently visited fragment and clicking the corresponding button to return to the previous fragment in the ViewPager works (i.e. interface responds and code executes successfully). However when ViewPager.setCurrentItem() is called in my FragmentStatePagerAdapter, the ViewPager does not return to the previous fragment.

More specifically, mViewPager.setCurrentItem() seems to have no action in my FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Here is my FragmentStatePagerAdapter; implements my OnClickListener interface:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements GeneralInformationClickListener {

    private List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    ViewPagerAdapter(ViewPager pViewPager, FragmentManager pFragmentManager) {
        super(pFragmentManager);
        mViewPager = pViewPager;

        // Create a new fragments needed for profile
        // passing 'this' an instance of an GeneralInformationClickListener
            mFragments.add(MainProfileFragment.newInstance(this));
        mFragments.add(GeneralInformationFragment.newInstance(this));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    /**
     * Handles what should happen when a button is
     * clicked within a fragment.
     *
     * This method cycles through all the fragments
     */
    @Override
    public void onNextClick() {
        if (mFragments.size() <= 1) {
            // No fragments to cycle between
            return;
        }

        if (mFragments.size() - 1 == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
            // We're at the last fragment, start at beginning
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
        } else {
            // Go to the next fragment
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my main fragment which contains the ViewPager and sets its adapter:

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    NonSwipeableViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_fragment, container, false);

        mViewPager = (NonSwipeableViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.profileViewPager);

        mViewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(
                mViewPager,
            getChildFragmentManager()));

    return view;
}
```

}

And here is the first fragment that my ViewPager holds:

```
 public class MainProfileFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

        public MainProfileFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        public static MainProfileFragment newInstance(GeneralInformationClickListener pListener) {
            MainProfileFragment fragment = new MainProfileFragment();
            fragment.setNextClickListener(pListener);
            return fragment;
        }

        private void setNextClickListener(GeneralInformationClickListener pListener) {
            mListener = pListener;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // If the button was clicked, notify the listener
            if (v.getId() == R.id.generalInformation
                    && mListener != null) {
                mListener.onNextClick();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_profile, container, false);

            // attach on click listener to the button
            Button generalInformation = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.generalInformation);

            generalInformation.setOnClickListener(this);

            return view;
        }
    }
```

And the second fragment in my ViewPager:

```
public class GeneralInformationFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private GeneralInformationClickListener mListener;

    public GeneralInformationFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @return A new instance of fragment GeneralInformationFragment.
     */
    public static GeneralInformationFragment newInstance(GeneralInformationClickListener pListener) {
        GeneralInformationFragment fragment = new GeneralInformationFragment();
        fragment.setNextClickListener(pListener);
        return fragment;
    }


    private void setNextClickListener(GeneralInformationClickListener pListener) {
        mListener = pListener;
    }

    /**
     * Check to see if the fragment is in focus and then add a back button if so
     * @param visible determines visibility of fragment
     */
    @Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(boolean visible) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(visible);

        if (visible) {
            toolbarIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24px);
            toolbarIcon.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_general_information, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.wellness_icon
                && mListener != null) {

            // Remove back button
            toolbarIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.wellness_icon);

            // Go to previous fragment
            mListener.onNextClick();
            toolbarIcon.setOnClickListener(null);

        }
    }
}
```

And finally my onclick interface:

```
public interface GeneralInformationClickListener {
    void onNextClick();
}
```

My interface implementation is fully functional so I feel like I may not be storing fragments inside my viewpager correctly.